# How to get cell value from one raster within a raster catalog using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, raster-catalog

I need to be able to obtain the cell value of one cell in one specific raster that is stored withing a raster catalog in a file geodatabase.  The **[Get Cell Value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m8000000)** tool doesn't appear to be able to do this on a Raster Catalog.

Using python, how does one go about doing this?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this interactively via a Python Add-In?  If so, are you using ArcGIS 10.1 or 10.2?  Or were you thinking of developing a "Get Cell Value(s) From Raster Catalog" Python script tool?  The pseudocode in either case is straightforward - use X,Y to look up what polygon(s) from the raster catalog index are at that location to read the disk location(s) of those raster datasets and do GetCellValue against it/them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of ArcMap you are running, but you might want to look into using a mosaic dataset instead. From the help on [raster data organization](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000n000000):

> The raster catalog has been superceded by the mosaic dataset, which
>   has many more capabilities, uses, and functions. Therefore, it is
>   recommended that you manage raster data using a mosaic dataset instead
>   of using a raster catalog.

I just created a mosaic dataset and it does support GetCellValue().

Comment: Ok, that may be true, but you cannot specify which exact raster from which you wish to obtain using GetCellValue, only the band index.  I have overlapping raster images that need to stay unique, so putting them into a virtual mosaicked state (a mosaic dataset) removes that ability unless I'm missing some functionality that I haven't seen.